# Define a tidyverse-function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data.frame `df` and I would like to do some checks on the data. If there's an error (e.g. missing values or non plausible values) I would like to make a list containing the id of the case and the type of error.

```
# Define an empty data.frame
errors <- data.frame(id = numeric(),
                     message = character())

# Function that stacks all the errors
addErrorMessage(message){
  
  errors <- rbind(errors,   )  # <= what to do here?
  
}

df <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                 var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 9, 4, 5),
                 var2 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", NA, "D", "A"))


########### List of checks ################
# Check 1: var1 should be smaller than 5
df %>% filter(var1 > 5) %>%
  addErrorMsg(message = "Value of var1 is 5 or greater")

# Check 2: var2 should not be missing
df %>% filter(is.na(var2)) %>%
  addErrorMessage(message = "Value of var2 is missing")
```

My question is: How can I define a function `addErrorMessage()` that I can directly use in the tidyverse-workflow? I want to avoid to save the wrong cases to a temporary data.frame for each check and then stack this data.frame on the `errors`-data.frame using `rbind()`.

Comment: You can’t, in the current form: since the function is called *after* `filter`, only the filtered subset is getting passed to the function. You need to rethink the design. But apart from this the function could just be a regular function, there’s nothing specific to the tidyverse.

Comment: I dont really understand. Isn't that the whole point, that only the filtered subset should be passed to the function as only the filtered subset contains the incorrect data?

Comment: Sure, but then your function cannot work with the original data. If I understand you correctly, the function should return the *full* table, not just a subset of it.

Comment: The data.frame `errors` was defined outside the function and should be updated within the function. The function does not necessarily have to return something. But it would of course also be fine to pass the `errors`-data.frame as an argument in the function call.

Comment: That isn’t how R works: functions generally don’t “update” data; they *return* modified data. Attempting to modify data instead of returning it is almost always a mistake in R. But even if we (unwisely) ignored this rule, the code you’ve posted couldn’t do this: how would your function know which table to modify, if the table isn’t passed to it?

Comment: But if I pass the `errors`-data.frame to the function each time I call it, this data.frame can be updated (append the new error messages) by the function and be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual problem can probably be solved using the [{pointblank}](https://rich-iannone.github.io/pointblank/) package which contains a lot of functions that help to conduct this and similar tests.

If you are more interested in writing such validation functions yourself, see a very rough draft below.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                 var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 9, 4, 5),
                 var2 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", NA, "D", "A"))


library(pointblank)

df %>% 
  col_vals_lt(vars(var1),
              value = 5) %>% 
  col_vals_not_null(vars(var2))
```

```
#> Error: Exceedance of failed test units where values in `var1` should have been < `5`.
#> The `col_vals_lt()` validation failed beyond the absolute threshold level (1).
#> * failure level (2) >= failure threshold (1)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

{pointblank} can also generate data validation reports:

```r
agent <- 
  create_agent(
    tbl = df,
    tbl_name = "My data",
    label = "Checking column values",
    actions = action_levels(stop_at = 1)
  ) %>%
  col_vals_lt(vars(var1),
              value = 5) %>% 
  col_vals_not_null(vars(var2)) %>% 
  interrogate()

agent
```

[image]

If you are more interested in writing this kind of functions yourself, below is a very rough draft. It uses the attributes of the underyling `data.frame` which is not a great solution, since depending on the functions you use in between `check`s the attributes might get lost. In a package we could use a dedicated environment to capture errors, so in this case we wouldn't need the attributes.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                 var1 = c(10, 2, 3, 3, 9, 4, 5),
                 var2 = c("A", NA, "B", "C", NA, "D", "A"))


check <- function(data, condition, message){ 
  
  exp  <- rlang::enexpr(condition)
  test  <- transmute(data, new = eval(exp))$new
  
  if (any(test)) {
    err_df <- attr(data, "error_df")
    if (is.null(err_df)) {
      attr(data, "error_df") <- data.frame(check   = 1L,
                                           row_nr  = which(test),
                                           message = message)
    } else {
      attr(data, "error_df") <- rbind(err_df,
                                      data.frame(check   = max(err_df$check) + 1L,
                                                 row_nr  = which(test),
                                                 message = message)
      )
    }
  }
  data
}

get_errors <- function(data) {
  print(attr(data,"error_df"))
  invisible(data)
}


df %>% 
  check(condition = var1 > 5,
        message = "Value of var1 is 5 or greater") %>% 
  check(condition = is.na(var2),
        message = "Value of var2 is missing") %>% 
  get_errors
#>   check row_nr                       message
#> 1     1      1 Value of var1 is 5 or greater
#> 2     1      5 Value of var1 is 5 or greater
#> 3     2      2      Value of var2 is missing
#> 4     2      5      Value of var2 is missing
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help, which is very helpful, even though I dont really understand what `condition = ~ .x %>% filter(var1 > 5)` does . In you solution the id of the case where `var1 > 5`  is 1, but it should be 5 as the 5ft case has a value of 9. In the second check the id should be 5 as the 5fth case has a missing value.

Comment: In the function defined above `id` is just an id which shows the number of the `check` function in which the “error” was raised. If I’m back at a computer I’ll give it a try to show the row numbers instead.

Comment: @D.Studer: see my updated answer. The `error_df` now captures the number of the `check` function together with the `row_nr`. Further the syntax is further simplified  - we do not need an anonymous function in the `condition` argument, but can just use any logical expression.